# how to center my text that has background-color of limited width and absolute position

Tags: css, positioning, background-color, css-position, centering

Maybe I am trying to much but What I want to do is to put the post title above the featured image on my page. I got it to work by possitioning the text, but of course this stops my page from being a responsive page. 
What I am looking for is to have text with a background colour of a certain width (so not spread from left to right) to be automatically centered and in absolute position. 
Is this possible?

This is what I have until now:

```
<style>
.post_title 
{
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-size: 14px; 
color: #fff; 
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
background-color: #0E0EFF; 
display:table; 
margin:auto; 
width: 40%; 
padding: 3px; 
border-radius: 2px;
} 
</style>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I have been looking for the answer for hours now.

Thx!

Comment: "What I am looking for is to have text with a background colour of a certain width (so not spread from left to right)" That's against Nature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but you can try to put a wrapper around the .post_title, let's say `div class="titlewrapper"`

Apply styles something like this:

```
div.titlewrapper {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

div.titlewrapper .post_title {
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #fff; 
    width:auto;        
    background-color: #0E0EFF; 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:auto; 
    padding: 3px; 
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Groet, Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Could [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/6WME5/) work for you?

CSS:

```
.center_title {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.post_title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #0E0EFF;
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center_title">
    <div class="post_title">test</div>
</div>
```

Try not to use Positions, only if you really need to!

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. This is so close to what I need. But the problem is that still the text is half behind my feature image, while i need it to be in front of it. This is why I used the position:absolute. 

Is there any solution for this?